# Hide a Folder Using Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am downloading a storing a set of files in a separate folders in My Documents . Is it possible to hide this folder.

I am creating an application which runs Out Of Browser and Has Elevated Permissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the proper permissions and that the folder exists at the correct path:

```
File.SetAttributes(@"..\foo\bar", FileAttributes.Hidden);
```